# Eigenvalues of Laplacian and eigenvalues of curvature operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, laplacian

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold (without boundary). The symmetries of the curvature $R$ of (the Levi-Civita connection associated to) $g$ allow one to realise $R$ as a self-adjoint (with respect to the induced metric on $\Lambda^2(T^{\ast}M)$) operator $$\mathfrak{R} : \Lambda^2(T^{\ast} M) \to \Lambda^2(T^{\ast} M).$$

> **Question.** Is there any relationship between the eigenvalues of $\mathfrak{R}$ and those of some Laplacian operator (e.g., Laplace-Beltrami,
> rough, etc.)?